# How to use directory operations in C++Builder?

Tags: directory, c++builder, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

I am stuck in creating a directory with C++Builder. If you check this [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.IOUtils.TDirectory.CreateDirectory#Properties) and [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Tokyo/en/DirectoryOperations_(C%2B%2B)), I find examples for my case, but when I try to use them, none of them work for me! For example, the following code for creating a directory, where the `edSourcePath->Text` value has been defined.

Unfortunately the documentation is not complete.

```
try
{
    /* Create directory to specified path */
    TDirectory::CreateDirectory(edSourcePath->Text);
}
catch (...)
{
    /* Catch the possible exceptions */
    MessageDlg("Incorrect path", mtError, TMsgDlgButtons() << mbOK, NULL);
    return;
}
```

The error message says `TDirectory` is not a class or namespace.

Another question is, how can I pass the source path and directory name by `CreateDirectory(edSourcePath->Text)`?

Comment: The compiler obviously can't find the description of the TDirectory class, so it simply doesn't know what a TDirectory is. Since you use `::` it assumes it must be a class or namespace. That is why you get the error message as it is. You'll have to #include the .hpp file that contains it, probably something like `#include "System.Ioutils.hpp"`.

Comment: So the source column in the documentation is what I miss. Thanks.

Comment: The "source column" shows the Wiki format source code for the webpage, not the C++ source code. Not very helpful.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis The "Source" column within the documentation text specifies the `.pas` file that implements the Pascal source code for the item being documented, and the `.hpp` file that needs to be included in C++ code to use the item. So, in this case, `System.IOUtils.pas` and `System.IOUtils.hpp`, respectively.  Maybe you are thinking of the "View Source" tab at the very top of the documentation?  That is for the Wiki page source code.

Comment: @Remy: now I am confused. I don't see any "Source" column anywhere in the docwiki.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis go to any function doc page (for example, [the one in the question](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.IOUtils.TDirectory.CreateDirectory)). Between the function declarations and the Description is a Properties table with 5 columns: Type, Visibility, **Source**, Unit, and Parent.

Comment: @Remy: <facepalm> Ooooh, now I see what you guys mean. Sorry for being obtuse, even after two cups of coffee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is a *compile-time* error, not a runtime error.  The compiler cannot find the definition of the `TDirectory` class.  You need to `#include` the header file that `TDirectory` is defined in, eg:

```cpp
#include <System.IOUtils.hpp> // <-- add this!

try
{
    /* Create directory to specified path */
    TDirectory::CreateDirectory(edSourcePath->Text);

    // or, if either DELPHIHEADER_NO_IMPLICIT_NAMESPACE_USE or
    // NO_USING_NAMESPACE_SYSTEM_IOUTILS is defined, you need
    // to use the fully qualified name instead:
    //
    // System::Ioutils::TDirectory::CreateDirectory(edSourcePath->Text);
}
catch (const Exception &e)
{
    /* Catch the possible exceptions */
    MessageDlg("Incorrect path.\n" + e.Message, mtError, TMsgDlgButtons() << mbOK, NULL);
    return;
}
```

Note, however, that `TDirectory::CreateDirectory()` throws an exception ONLY if the input `String` is not a valid formatted path.  It DOES NOT throw an exception if the actual directory creation fails.  In fact, there is no way to detect that condition with `TDirectory::CreateDirectory()` itself, you would have to check with `TDirectory::Exists()` afterwards:

```cpp
#include <System.IOUtils.hpp>

try
{
    /* Create directory to specified path */
    String path = edSourcePath->Text;
    TDirectory::CreateDirectory(path);
    if (!TDirectory::Exists(path))
        throw Exception("Error creating directory");
}
catch (const Exception &e)
{
    /* Catch the possible exceptions */
    MessageDlg(e.Message, mtError, TMsgDlgButtons() << mbOK, NULL);
    return;
}
```

Otherwise, `TDirectory::CreateDirectory()` is just a validating wrapper for [`System::Sysutils::ForceDirectories()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.ForceDirectories), which has a `bool` return value.  So, you could just call that function directly instead:

```cpp
#include <System.SysUtils.hpp>

/* Create directory to specified path */
if (!ForceDirectories(edSourcePath->Text)) // or: System::Sysutils::ForceDirectories(...), if needed
{
    MessageDlg("Error creating directory", mtError, TMsgDlgButtons() << mbOK, NULL);
    return;
}
```

Comment: I find old documentation, that provide example like your last code, (http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/SysUtils_CreateDir.html) I like to ask you what is advantage of using `throw Exception()` and `MessageDlg()`? Thanks.

Comment: @AlirezaNazari purely up to personal coding style

Answer (score 0):

Now that's strange !...
I looked everywhere for my IOUtils but I could only find (For my insallation of Borland BCB v 4 (yes v4 sorry) a file called "sysutils.hpp"
in the C: Program Files (x86) Borland CBuilder4 Include Vcl directory.... In it I found from a text search for createdir an entry thus...

```
`extern PACKAGE bool __fastcall CreateDir(const AnsiString Dir);`
```

I placed a button click event....
    `void __fastcall TForm1::Button2Click(TObject *Sender) { CreateDir("Big"); }`

and this created a directory called "Big" in the current directory !

Kevin (Tinwizard)